# Matching a string in one file and want to print the value written after that string in certain file

Tags: perl, string-matching

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $file, "<", "abc.txt") || die ("Cannot open file.\n");
open(my $out, ">", "output.txt") || die ("Cannot open file.\n");

while (my $line =<$file>) {
chomp $line;
if ($line =~ /\+vth\d = (\d+)/) {
print $out "$1\n";
  }
}
```

abc.txt

```
.lib cmos_models

.model  nmos  nmos  level = 54

+version = 4.0          binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 1          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          

+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.75e-9      toxp    = 1.1e-9       toxm    = 1.75e-9   
+dtox    = 0.65e-9      epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 3.75e-009   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.75e-9   
+xl      = -20e-9

+vth0    = 0.466        k1      = 0.4          k2      = 0.0          k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 1            dvt1    = 2       
+dvt2    = 0            dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.1          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1.0e-010     
+dvtp1   = 0.1          lpe0    = 0            lpeb    = 0            xj      = 1.4e-008   
+ngate   = 2e+020       ndep    = 3.24e+018    nsd     = 2e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000        cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.13        nfactor = 2.1          eta0    = 0.0049       etab    = 0          
+vfb     = -0.55        u0      = 0.04398      ua      = 6e-010       ub      = 1.2e-018     
+uc      = 0            vsat    = 147390       a0      = 1.0          ags     = 0     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1.0          b0      = 0            b1      = 0          
+keta    = 0.04         dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.02       
+pdiblc1 = 0.001        pdiblc2 = 0.001        pdiblcb = -0.005       drout   = 0.5        
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 1e-007     
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.08         pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 5            rdsw    = 155          rsw     = 80           rdw     = 80        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0          
+prwb    = 0            wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002     
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004      
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.012        bigc    = 0.0028     
+cigc    = 0.002        aigsd   = 0.012        bigsd   = 0.0028       cigsd   = 0.002     
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1          

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 1.1e-010     cgdo    = 1.1e-010     cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.653e-10     
+cgsl    = 2.653e-10    ckappas = 0.03         ckappad = 0.03         acde    = 1          
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       

+kt1     = -0.11        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = 0.022        ute     = -1.5       
+ua1     = 4.31e-009    ub1     = 7.61e-018    uc1     = -5.6e-011    prt     = 0          
+at      = 33000      

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 3e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0.0e-008     xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1          

* PTM 45nm PMOS

.model  pmos  pmos  level = 54

+version = 4.0          binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 1          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          

+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.85e-009    toxp    = 1.1e-009     toxm    = 1.85e-009   
+dtox    = 0.75e-9      epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 3.75e-009   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.85e-009   
+xl      = -20e-9

+vth0    = 40      k1      = 0.4          k2      = -0.01        k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 1            dvt1    = 2       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.1          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-011     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 0            lpeb    = 0            xj      = 1.4e-008   
+ngate   = 2e+020       ndep    = 2.44e+018    nsd     = 2e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000        cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.126       nfactor = 2.1          eta0    = 0.0049       etab    = 0          
+vfb     = 0.55         u0      = 0.00440      ua      = 2.0e-009     ub      = 0.5e-018     
+uc      = 0            vsat    = 70000        a0      = 1.0          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = 0            b1      = 0          
+keta    = -0.047       dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.12       
+pdiblc1 = 0.001        pdiblc2 = 0.001        pdiblcb = 3.4e-008     drout   = 0.56       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 9.58e-007  
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.08         pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 5            rdsw    = 155          rsw     = 75           rdw     = 75        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0  
+prwb    = 0            wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002     
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004      
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.69         bigc    = 0.0012     
+cigc    = 0.0008       aigsd   = 0.0087       bigsd   = 0.0012       cigsd   = 0.0008     
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1 

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 1.1e-010     cgdo    = 1.1e-010     cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.653e-10
+cgsl    = 2.653e-10    ckappas = 0.03         ckappad = 0.03         acde    = 1
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02

+kt1     = -0.11        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = 0.022        ute     = -1.5       
+ua1     = 4.31e-009    ub1     = 7.61e-018    uc1     = -5.6e-011    prt     = 0          
+at      = 33000      

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 3e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0.0e-008     xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1  

.model  pmos  pmos  level = 54

+version = 4.0          binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 1          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          

+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.85e-009    toxp    = 1.1e-009     toxm    = 1.85e-009   
+dtox    = 0.75e-9      epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 3.75e-009   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.85e-009   
+xl      = -20e-9

+vth0    = 50 k1      = 0.4          k2      = -0.01        k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 1            dvt1    = 2       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.1          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-011     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 0            lpeb    = 0            xj      = 1.4e-008   
+ngate   = 2e+020       ndep    = 2.44e+018    nsd     = 2e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000        cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.126       nfactor = 2.1          eta0    = 0.0049       etab    = 0          
+vfb     = 0.55         u0      = 0.00440      ua      = 2.0e-009     ub      = 0.5e-018     
+uc      = 0            vsat    = 70000        a0      = 1.0          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = 0            b1      = 0          
+keta    = -0.047       dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.12       
+pdiblc1 = 0.001        pdiblc2 = 0.001        pdiblcb = 3.4e-008     drout   = 0.56       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 9.58e-007  
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.08         pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 5            rdsw    = 155          rsw     = 75           rdw     = 75        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0  
+prwb    = 0            wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002     
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004      
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.69         bigc    = 0.0012     
+cigc    = 0.0008       aigsd   = 0.0087       bigsd   = 0.0012       cigsd   = 0.0008     
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1 

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 1.1e-010     cgdo    = 1.1e-010     cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.653e-10
+cgsl    = 2.653e-10    ckappas = 0.03         ckappad = 0.03         acde    = 1
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02

+kt1     = -0.11        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = 0.022        ute     = -1.5       
+ua1     = 4.31e-009    ub1     = 7.61e-018    uc1     = -5.6e-011    prt     = 0          
+at      = 33000      

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 3e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0.0e-008     xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1  

.model  pmos  pmos  level = 54

+version = 4.0          binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 1          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          

+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.85e-009    toxp    = 1.1e-009     toxm    = 1.85e-009   
+dtox    = 0.75e-9      epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 3.75e-009   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.85e-009   
+xl      = -20e-9

+vth0    = 60      k1      = 0.4          k2      = -0.01        k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 1            dvt1    = 2       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.1          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-011     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 0            lpeb    = 0            xj      = 1.4e-008   
+ngate   = 2e+020       ndep    = 2.44e+018    nsd     = 2e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000        cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.126       nfactor = 2.1          eta0    = 0.0049       etab    = 0          
+vfb     = 0.55         u0      = 0.00440      ua      = 2.0e-009     ub      = 0.5e-018     
+uc      = 0            vsat    = 70000        a0      = 1.0          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = 0            b1      = 0          
+keta    = -0.047       dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.12       
+pdiblc1 = 0.001        pdiblc2 = 0.001        pdiblcb = 3.4e-008     drout   = 0.56       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 9.58e-007  
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.08         pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 5            rdsw    = 155          rsw     = 75           rdw     = 75        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0  
+prwb    = 0            wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002     
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004      
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.69         bigc    = 0.0012     
+cigc    = 0.0008       aigsd   = 0.0087       bigsd   = 0.0012       cigsd   = 0.0008     
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1 

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 1.1e-010     cgdo    = 1.1e-010     cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.653e-10
+cgsl    = 2.653e-10    ckappas = 0.03         ckappad = 0.03         acde    = 1
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02

+kt1     = -0.11        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = 0.022        ute     = -1.5       
+ua1     = 4.31e-009    ub1     = 7.61e-018    uc1     = -5.6e-011    prt     = 0          
+at      = 33000      

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 3e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0.0e-008     xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1  

.endl
```

There are 4 vth0 in file. At least 4 spaces between vth0 and =, at least one space between = and corresponding value. One more thing what if I need to read only last 3 vth0 values, skipping first one. What changes I have to make.

Comment: @fugu..please see the actual problem

Comment: Woah, unintelligible wall of text. Please see [ask] for how to make a good question. What's desirable: A clear description of your problem. Some sample data. Some code that illustrates your problem. A desired result.

Answer (score 3):

There are more than one whitespace after `vth\d` and you are matching just one whitespace. You should match all whitespaces:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $file, "<", "abc.txt") || die ("Cannot open file.\n");
open(my $out, ">", "output.txt") || die ("Cannot open file.\n");

while (my $line = <$file>)
{
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /\+vth\d\s+=\s+(\d+)/)
    {
        print $out "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Here `\s+` will match one or more whitespaces.

Output:

```
0
40
50
60
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s` in a regex to match whitespace.

If you want to skip the first occurrence, keep a flag that tells you whether it was already skipped:

```
my $skip = 1;
while (<$INPUT>) {
    if (/vth\d\s*=\s*(\d+)/) {
        if ($skip) {
            undef $skip; # Don't skip the following occurences.
        } else {
            print "$1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @choroba...solved my problem..thanks mate...can you please explain the flag?..How this code is missing the first occurence

Comment: @Suhan: if `$skip` is set, then on the first occurrence, it goes to the `if true` branch which resets the flag, but prints nothing. On subsequent occurrences, the `else` branch is invoked which prints the output.

Answer (score 0):

> At least 4 spaces between vth0 and =, at least one space between = and
>   corresponding value.

```
vth\d\s{4,}=\s+(\d+)
```

> read only last 3 vth0 values, skipping first one.

Use a flag and if/else blocks to `next` on first match (or whatever condition you want)